ActionMode callback in Compose for Text
In AppCompatTextView, there is a possibility of setting custom selection action mode callback i.e.
fun setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(@Nullable ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback)

And with this, we can listen to what action (copy, cut,share) does the user selects.
ActionMode options with AppCompatTextView
I tried the to replicate the same thing in Compose. For this, I used a SelectionContainer  and put the Composable Text  inside:
SelectionContainer {
    Text(
        text = "This is the text that I want to copy",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

With the SelectionContainer, I am only see the "Copy" action available after the selection:
Action mode available with SelectionContainer
Question 1: Is it possible to get the same action mode options with Compose Text as we get with the AppCompatTextView?
Question 2: Is it possible to listen to the action selected by the user with the composable Text by using the ActionMode callback for it?
